# ROS Navigation Goal Trigger

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all
I have a question, is there a way to take the navigation goal when a real robot reaches a goal as a trigger to operate a motor like a stepper motor for example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402636/ros-navigation-goal-trigger/) by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, if you use `move_base` you can use its published topics:
https://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Action_API

> #### Action Published Topics
>
> `move_base/feedback`
> (`move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionFeedback`)
>
> ```
> Feedback contains the current position of the base in the world.
> ```
>
> `move_base/status`
> (`actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray`)
>
> ```
> Provides status information on the goals that are sent to the move_base
> ```
>
> action.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) on 2022-06-21**:
Thanks alot

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-06-21**:
If it answers your question, you can mark it as correct, so the question will be marked as solved in the queue